# Группировка UITableView, аналогично приложению Контакты на iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Не могу разобраться, как реализована группировка например в приложении Контакты на iOS.
У меня есть массив объектов - друзей и два массива: 1ый с первыми буквами фамилий, 2ой с количеством друзей имеющих эти буквы.

```
var friends: [Friend] = Friend.allFriends()
var countFirstLetter: (letter: [String], repetition: [Int]) = Friend.countFirstLetter()
var countFriends = 0


//MARK: - Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

// MARK: - Table view

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return countFirstLetter.letter.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return countFirstLetter.repetition[section]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return countFirstLetter.letter[section]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendCell", for: indexPath) as! FriendCell
    
    cell.configureCell(friend: friends[indexPath.item + countFriends])
    countFriends += 1
    
    return cell
}
```

Не могу разобраться, как работает переопредление ячеек и почему элементы повторяются
[image: Запускаю приложение, все хорошо, кроме того, что счётчик как-то криво работает и пропускает часть друзей]

[image: Но после прокрутки вниз и возврата - ячейки меняются на новые и как кончаются элементы - таблица крашится]

Два вопроса:

1. Как узнать, какую секцию заполняет таблица. Тогда я смогу исправить проблему на первом фото и увеличивать Count только, когда меняется секция.
2. Как решить проблему с перезаполнением ячеек, чтобы в строке оставался нужный элемент

Answer (score 0):

indexPath в каждой секции свой, т.е. есть indexPath.section и indexPath.row (это к вопросу как узнать, какая сейчас секция заполняется), поэтому у вас indexPath.item в каждой секции начинается сначала и элементы повторяются. Можно сделать просто cell.configureCell(friend: friends[countFriends]). Хотя это не очень гибкое решение, лучше сделать массив секций, в котором будем номер секции и массив ячеек секции: [section, [rows]]:

```
    struct Objects {
        var sectionName : String
        var sectionObjects : [String]
    }
    
    var objectArray = [Objects]()

 // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectArray.count
    }        
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return objectArray[section].sectionName
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```